# How to Export/Import ADUsers from WinSrv2003 to WinSrv2016 using CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, export-to-csv, csvde

I got a WinSrv2003 with an Active Directory (old domain, about 80 Users) and a freshly installed WinSrv2016 with an blank AD (new domain, different name). I want to avoid migrating the Users by Hand.

Using csvde I got a list of the Users with every attribute (-l *). I cut it down, left the necessary Attributes (plus 3 additional for comfort) and changed the old domain information to the new one ("manually" in Excel afterwards). I saved the CSV and tried importing the Users with "csvde -i ..." but the CLI said that the attribute list could not be read.

After that I tried to import the Users via PowerShell but got an Error saying that attribute xy (ou in this case) is not "unique". (I'm german and don't know the english error words)

Since I am german I thought that it might be an Excel problem since Excel change commas and semicolons in Germany, but Powershell seemed to get the different columns, so...

Thanks!
(I'm new to stackoverflow so if sth is missing or so I can provide more information)

---

Used attributes w example:

DN - CN=John Smith,OU=Unit,DC=domain,DC=local

objectClass - user

ou - [empty]

distingueshedName - CN=John Smith,OU=Unit,DC=domain,DC=local

name - John Smith

cn - John Smith

sn - Smith

givenName - John

displayName - John Smith

homeDirectory - \\10.10.10.10\home$\john.smith

homedrive - S:

scriptpath - logon-script.cmd

samaccountname - john.smith

userprincipalname - john.smith@domain.local

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do it once, you can download a trial version of an app like Adaxes with nice GUI and do all the import/export stuff there. They've also got [a tutorial](https://www.adaxes.com/tutorials_ActiveDirectoryManagement_ImportUserAccountsFromCSVFile.htm#powershell) about importing users via PowerShell and how your CSV should be structured to make it work perfectly if you decide to go the PowerShell route.